# Equal gap between three floating divs

Tags: html, css

I got three divs, each at a random size, while I want to have each gap at the same width (dotted lines):

Some examples:

```
<Left Div>...............<Mid Div>..............<Right Div>
<Larger Left Div>...........<Mid Div>...........<Right Div>
<Left Div>...........<Mid Div>...........<Larger Right Div>
```

I can easily align the left and right div using `float: left;` and `float: right;`, but can not figure how to center the mid div. I have considered using `flexbox` or `tables` or playing around using `text-align: justify;`

I have made a **[JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/byawgp16/)** to play with, if its helpful. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just display your center `div` as `inline-block` and use `text-align: center` on your container. With this solution you will not have problems with browser support.

```css
.mainframe {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.center {
  display: inline-block;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainframe">
  <div class="center">"Center Me!"</div>
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a great solution without any necessary fallbacks! I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 10):

With `Flexbox` you can use `justify-content: space-between`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.mainframe {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainframe">
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="center">"Center Me!"</div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You gotta love flex! :)

Comment: Thanks for this great solution. As I try to keep the site as simple as possible I try to avoid flexbox as long as I can, so I choose the version without any required fallbacks.

Comment: @Marian Rick You're welcome, sure choose whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worry about browser support, then you can rely on `table`. Here's how you do it

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.mainframe {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* For cells of equal size */
}
.mainframe div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainframe">
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="center">"Center Me!"</div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
```